# Get Current User after SignInStatus.Success

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have a mvc app and I´m using Asp Identity 2.0. I need to change some User information after the login, so I need to get the current user just after login. I´m using the following code

```
       var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

Just after

```
       case SignInStatus.Success:
```

But I´m getting null as result. Usually when I use UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()) in the Controllers it works fine. Don´t know what is happening now.

Comment: Show all your sign-in method. `User.Identity.GetUserId()` gives you the ID of a logged-in user from the cookie, but at that stage the cookie is not set yet (even if you have `SignInStatus.Success`) - cookie with user identity is created only on request complete.